# Create a pandas Dataframe from a nested dict with row indices as dict keys and a dict with different columns per key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict of the form:

```py
    pd_dict = {'row_id_1': {'col_1': val1, 'col_2': val2},
               'row_id_2': {'col_1': val3, 'col_3': val4, 'col_4': val5}
               ...
              }
```

and I would like to turn this into a pandas DataFrame:

```
            col_1    col_2    col_3    col4    ...
row_id_1    val1     val2     NaN      NaN
row_id_2    val3     NaN      val4     val5
...
```

The number of columns per row differs. The same columns may or may not repeat on different rows. I'd like to merge all and fill in NaN values where appropriate.

I tried:

```py
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd_dict, orient='index')
```

...but that doesn't give the correct output.

I also tried creating one DataFrame per row and then concat-ing them like so:

```py
frames = []
...
for k, cols in pd_dict.items():
    ...
    frames.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: list(cols.values())}, orient='index', columns=list(cols.keys())))
    ...
df = pd.concat(frames)
```

That works but it takes a very long time.

It's worth mentioning that my data has around 1000 rows and 1000 columns per row so performance might become an issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(pd_dict).T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to uneven `len` of `dict` .

```
pd.Series(pd_dict).apply(pd.Series)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd_dict).T
print(df)
#         col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4
#row_id_1  val1  val2   NaN   NaN
#row_id_2  val3   NaN  val4  val5
```

Also your original attempt would work if you sorted:

```
print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd_dict,orient='index').sort_index(1))
#         col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4
#row_id_1  val1  val2   NaN   NaN
#row_id_2  val3   NaN  val4  val5
```

Comment: I tried sort_index as per your suggestion but didnt work. Using transpose however did work but doesnt keep the order of columns (they appear to be sorted alphabetically). Is there a way to keep the order?

Comment: @capitan what version of python? Pre python 3.6, dictionaries are unordered. [Post 3.6 they maintain insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6/39980744). Dictionary key ordering aside, your question is a bit ambiguous as not all columns appear in all the dictionaries. How do you determine the correct order?

Comment: Im using python 3.7. All rows have the same first 3 columns (first keys in the dict values of pd_dict), so i'd like those to appear first. After that I dont really care about the order.